# Using C#, how do I read a text file into a matrix of characters and then query that matrix? Is this even possible?

Tags: c#, algorithm, parsing, text

## Example

If I had a text file with these lines:

1. The cat meowed.
2. The dog barked.
3. The cat ran up a tree.

I would want to end up with a matrix of rows and columns like this:

```
   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0| t-h-e- -c-a-t- -m-e-o-w-e-d-.- - - - - - - -
1| t-h-e- -d-o-g- -b-a-r-k-e-d-.- - - - - - - -
2| t-h-e- -c-a-t- -r-a-n- -u-p- -a- -t-r-e-e-.-
```

Then I would like to query this matrix to quickly determine information about the text file itself.  For example, I would quickly be able to tell if everything in column "0" is a "t" (it is).

I realize that this might seem like a strange thing to do.  I am trying to ultimately (among other things) determine if various text files are fixed-width delimited without any prior knowledge about the file.  I also want to use this matrix to detect patterns.

The actual files that will go through this are quite large.

Thanks!

Comment: Where exactly are you having difficulty? Loading the file? Obtaining the content as strings? Converting the strings to arrays? Querying the arrays?

Comment: `File.ReadAllLines("file.txt").Select(line => line.ToCharArray())` (Assuming a jagged array is fine.)

Comment: I simply have never had a need to create AND query a matrix, so I just need a little help getting started.  Thanks.

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt "create AND query a matrix" doesn't really make sense as a problem statement. This means that maybe you should think about what precisely you want to do more. What does "a matrix" mean? What's the problem in creating whatever that is? What kind of "query"?

Comment: Seems like an [XY-Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341)

Comment: @millimoose--your `File.ReadAllLines` suggestion got me half way to my goal, thanks.  In regards to your other question, how would I query to get a list of all columns that contain a `space` character for ALL rows (for example)?  Thanks!

Comment: Here is another more direct problem statement: How would I iterate the result of `File.ReadAllLines("file.txt").Select(line => line.ToCharArray())` by *columns* rather than by *rows*.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example, I would quickly be able to tell if everything in column "0" is a "t" (it is).

```
int column = 0;
char charToCheck = 't';

bool b = File.ReadLines(filename)
             .All(s => (s.Length > column ? s[column] : '\0') == charToCheck);
```

Comment: Nice, clean solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> "I am trying to ultimately (among other things) determine if various text files are fixed-width (...)"

If that's so, you could try this:

```
public bool isFixedWidth (string fileName)
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

    int length = lines[0].Length;
    foreach (string s in lines)
    {
        if (s.length != Length)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Once you get that `lines` variable, you can access any character as though they were in a matrix. Like `char c = lines[3][1];`. However, there is no hard guarantee that all lines are the same length. You could pad them to be the same length as the longest one, if you so wanted.

Also,

> "how would I query to get a list of all columns that contain a space character for ALL rows (for example)"

You could try this:

```
public bool CheckIfAllCharactersInAColumnAreTheSame (string[] lines, int colIndex)
{
    char c = lines[0][colIndex];
    try
    {
        foreach (string s in lines)
        {
            if (s[colIndex] != c)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (IndexOutOfRangeException ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is read the first line of your text file and use it as a mask. Compare every next line to the mask and remove every character from the mask that is not the same as the character at the same position. After processing al lines you'll have a list of delimiters.

Btw, code is not very clean but it is a good starter I think.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace DynamicallyDetectFixedWithDelimiter
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Temp\test.txt");

            // Get initial list of delimiters
            char[] firstLine = sr.ReadLine().ToCharArray();
            Dictionary<int, char> delimiters = new Dictionary<int, char>();
            for (int i = 0; i < firstLine.Count(); i++)
            {
                delimiters.Add(i, firstLine[i]);
            }

            // Read subsequent lines, remove delimeters from 
            // the dictionary that are not present in subsequent lines
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null && delimiters.Count() != 0)
            {
                var subsequentLine = line.ToCharArray();
                var invalidDelimiters = new List<int>();

                // Compare all chars in first and subsequent line
                foreach (var delimiter in delimiters)
                {
                    if (delimiter.Key >= subsequentLine.Count())
                    {
                        invalidDelimiters.Add(delimiter.Key);
                        continue;
                    }

                    // Remove delimiter when it differs from the 
                    // character at the same position in a subsequent line
                    if (subsequentLine[delimiter.Key] != delimiter.Value)
                    {
                        invalidDelimiters.Add(delimiter.Key);
                    }
                }
                foreach (var invalidDelimiter in invalidDelimiters)
                {
                    delimiters.Remove(invalidDelimiter);
                }
            }

            foreach (var delimiter in delimiters)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Delimiter at {0} = {1}", delimiter.Key, delimiter.Value));
            }

            sr.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer.  I chose a different answer as the winner only because of how direct and elegantly it answered the question, but your answer will help some folks out as well.  +1

Answer (score 0):

Since it's not clear where you're have difficulty exactly, here are a few pointers.

Reading the file as strings, one per line:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("filename.txt");
```

Obtaning a jagged array (a matrix) of characters from the lines (this step seems unnecessary since strings can be indexed just like character arrays):

```
char[][] charMatrix = lines.Select(l => l.ToCharArray()).ToArray();
```

Example query: whether every character in column 0 is a 't':

```
bool allTs = charMatrix.All(row => row[0] == 't');
```

Comment: every `row` is not the same length.  It would throw `index out of range` exception, say, for row[20] in question.

Comment: Sure. I was just going by the example described by the OP, which assumes every line has a character in position 0. More validation would be required for more general algorithms, the point was just to illustrate a simple example.